# PHP: Populate array in a recursive manner

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MySQL table that looks like this

```
-------------------------
field   |   parent_field
------------------------
model   |   series
height  |   series
height  |   model
length  |   model
length  |   height
```

The table is structure in this way, so each field can have multiple `parent_field`.

A user starts by choosing a *series*, then I need to get all fields that needs to be changed.

For example, I need to have a table that contains

```
$fields = array(
     'model' => [
         'name' => 'model'
      ],  

      'height' => [
         'name' => 'height'
      ],   

      'length' => [
         'name' => 'length'
      ]
);
```

So, although *length* doesn't have `parent_field` *series*, but had *height* which in turn has *series* as `parent_field`.

My logic is as follow

```
private function loadFields($parent) {
   $children = array();
   $children = $this->loadChildren();

   foreach($children as $child) {
      $data[$child->field][] = array(
         'name' => $child->field, 
          .
          .
          .        
      );
   }
}
```

The function `loadChildren()` does just that, it does a `SELECT DISTINCT` and return the children of the given parent.

HOWEVER, I need to keep loading children for the current children.

I am stuck, can anyone point me in the right direction ?

Comment: Do you know how to use recursion?  If you've never done it, prepare to have your mind seriously twisted.  Inside the `foreach` loop after you process each field you will call `loadFields($this)`.

Comment: What does $this refer to ? loadFields() takes as argument a string, in this case if should be $child->field

Comment: I think there are more problens in your code.  SHouldn't the second line be `$children=$parent->loadChildren()`?  In which the recursive call will be `loadfields($child)`

Answer (score 0):

You can acheive it directly with your SQL query using GROUP_CONCAT

```
SELECT field, GROUP_CONCAT(parent_field SEPARATOR ',') as parent_fields
FROM mytable GROUP BY field
```

Parsing the row you can just explode parent_fields on , and obtain the sub array you want with all the parent values in.